# MySql query for duplicate fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have sql table with fowling content:

```
id | joined              | ip
---------------------------------------
 1 | 2014-03-20 10:01:51 | 214.254.22.1
 2 | 2014-03-20 11:01:51 | 214.254.2.1
 5 | 2014-03-20 12:01:51 | 214.254.12.1
 8 | 2014-03-20 13:01:51 | 214.254.22.1
```

for example i want to find all results for `joined` after `2014-03-20 10:00:00` and `ip` found more  than once in all records

so in this case my result should be:

```
 1 | 2014-03-20 10:01:51 | 214.254.22.1
```

because its joined after 10:00:00 and the ip `214.254.22.1` is found 2 times in the database.

Is this kind of query possible at all?

Comment: Yes. Not only is it possible, it's also very easy! Unfortunate/confusing that the column is called 'joined' because by a strange coincidence, that's also the answer!

Comment: You don't need any counts or havings. You just need a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql> create table `t` (`id`  int, `joined` datetime, `ip` char(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)

mysql> insert into `t` values
    -> (1, '2014-03-20 10:01:51', '214.254.22.1'),
    -> (2, '2014-03-20 11:01:51', '214.254.2.1'),
    -> (5, '2014-03-20 12:01:51', '214.254.12.1'),
    -> (8, '2014-03-20 13:01:51', '214.254.22.1');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**[answer]** Query:

```
mysql> select *, count(`ip`) as total_ip  
    -> from `t` 
    -> where joined > '2014-03-20 10:00:00' 
    -> group by ip 
    -> having total_ip > 1 ;
+------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
| id   | joined              | ip           | total_ip |
+------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
|    1 | 2014-03-20 10:01:51 | 214.254.22.1 |        2 |
+------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ok, this one is working well, but lets say for example i have ids:
1,7,22,44 using same ip then this query will return that id: 1 is having total_ip: 4, which is correct, but can it display this one in reverse order - for example to show that id 44 is having total_ip of 4?
I mean to display the highest ID of all but not the lowest.

Comment: @V.Donchev yes possible, try this: `select *, count(\`ip\`) as total_ip from (select *  from \`t\` order by id desc) as t1 group by ip  having total_ip > 1;` .. but it would be slow.

Comment: @V.Donchev Check for id = 4, 7, 22, 44 [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2028ec/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Having` clause to filter for specific aggregates like the following:

```
select
    id,
    joined,
    count(ip)
from
    yourTable
where
    joined > yourDate
group by
    id,
    joined
having
    count(ip) > 1
```

You can find more information on this here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, joined, ip, count(ip) 
FROM tablename
WHERE joined > date  
HAVING count(ip) > 2
```

Comment: Its not working, it returns only one record no matter how may are with duplicate ip's

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,joined              DATETIME
,ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 1 ,'2014-03-20 10:01:51','214.254.22.1'),
( 2 ,'2014-03-20 11:01:51','214.254.2.1'),
( 5 ,'2014-03-20 12:01:51','214.254.12.1'),
( 8 ,'2014-03-20 13:01:51','214.254.22.1');
```

For your specific data set, the followign will suffice...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.ip = x.ip 
   AND y.joined > x.joined 
 WHERE x.joined > '2014-03-20 10:00:00';
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | joined              | ip           |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2014-03-20 10:01:51 | 214.254.22.1 |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

If there's a chance that the ip can appear more than once, you could consider wrapping this up in a subquery...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MIN(x.id) min_id 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.ip = x.ip 
          AND y.joined > x.joined 
        WHERE x.joined > '2014-03-20 10:00:00' 
        GROUP 
           BY x.ip
     ) b
    ON b.min_id = a.id;
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | joined              | ip           |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2014-03-20 10:01:51 | 214.254.22.1 |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```